# Spring Boot 1.5.2: class path resource [] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot

In my Spring Boot 1.5.2 application, I get the following exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
```

I read that it is a bug in Spring Boot 1.4.1 if there are no classes marked with `@Entity`, however, I am using a newer version and I also have classes annotated with `@Entity`, so I really don't know what the cause for the error could be.

My `SpringApplication` class is located in `org.common.deployment` and the entities in `org.common.deployment.model`, so the entities should be found if I annotate my `SpringApplication` class like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DeploymentBootstrapper {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DeploymentBootstrapper.class, args);
  }
  ...
}
```

The error only occurs when I build the project on a GitLab CI server, not if I run unit tests locally.

Comment: You dont need to annotate the app with `@EnableTransactionManagement`. It will enable based of classpath resources. Try removing it. 

https://spring.io/guides/gs/managing-transactions/

Answer (score -1):

I dont know if this is still a topic. I faced nearly the same problem. Working like a charm within the IDE and on the dev enviornment, but the application fails to start on the build systems with the error above.

The solution (at least on my end) was to place a orm.xml without any entities within META-INF. The annotated entities are still be found even with this file on the classpath.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<entity-mappings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_1.xsd"
                 version="2.1">
</entity-mappings>
```